# R - Convert seconds in to hours and minutes

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this,

```
Time ColA Colb
123  A     B
```

I would like to convert this into a dataframe like this,

```
Hours Minutes ColA Colb
0      2       A    B
```

The value in the time column is in the form of Seconds. How to convert this in to hours and minutes?

Comment: What about `df$Minutes<-  floor(df$Time/60)` and  `df$Hours<-  floor(df$Time/(60*60))`

Comment: Another option: `lubridate::seconds_to_period(df$Time)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reproduce a similar example using the following R code:

```
library("lubridate")
library("dplyr")

Data <- data.frame(Time = seq(from = 100, to = 1200, by = 100),
                   ColA = rnorm(n = 12, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                   ColB = rnorm(n = 12, mean = 10, sd = 1))
```

Which generates a DataFrame with three columns, as yours: Time, ColA and ColB. The result looks like this:

```
   Time    ColA      ColB
1  100  0.3819418  9.793732
2  200 -0.6819604  9.809536
3  300 -1.5910664 10.491511
4  400  0.5091230  8.251863
5  500  1.4298513 10.939813
```

Based on that you can use ***lubridate*** and ***dplyr*** libraries the get the result you are looking for, as follows:

```
Data %>%
    mutate(Hours = hour(seconds_to_period(Time)),
           Minutes = minute(seconds_to_period(Time))) %>%
    select(Hours, Minutes, ColA, ColB)
```

Which generates the following results:

```
     Hours Minutes   ColA      ColB
1      0       1  0.3819418  9.793732
2      0       3 -0.6819604  9.809536
3      0       5 -1.5910664 10.491511
4      0       6  0.5091230  8.251863
5      0       8  1.4298513 10.939813
```

The logic behind that code is the following:

First, you are converting the seconds into a ***Period*** (lubridate's object to represent time lapses) using ***seconds_to_period()*** function. The result of that looks like this **"2H 23M 20S"** Then, using ***hour() and minute()*** you can extract the units you need, in this case hours and minutes. Finally, you can select the variables you want to keep using ***select()***. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Without additional packages you could make use of `%/%`, i.e. integer division (similar to A. Suliman's solution in the comments):

```
df$Hour <- df$Time %/% (60 * 60)
df$Minute <- df$Time %/% 60
df
#  Time ColA Colb Hour Minute
#1  123    A    B    0      2
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "Time ColA Colb
123  A     B", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```